# Create reference between Entity Framework domains

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a domain called `Item` and a domain called `Category`. I want to add the PK of the category to the `Item` but I am not sure how to do this in EF 6

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = GuidCombGenerator.GenerateComb();
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = GuidCombGenerator.GenerateComb();
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
}
```

I thought I could do this

```
var item = new Item
                {
                    CategoryId =  dto.CategoryId ,
                    Name = dto.Name.Trim(),
                };

dbContext.StorageItems.Add(item);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I added another property called `CategoryId` and filled this in with the correct `Id`. However this goes and make a new `Category` entry instead of just linking the 2 up.

I thought I could do this but maybe I am mixing it up with NHibernate.

I then tried this (did not think this would work):

```
var item = new item
                {
                    Category = new Category { Id = dto.CategoryId, },
                    Name = dto.Name.Trim(),
                };

dbContext.StorageItems.Add(item);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

It does not like this at all.

The only option I can think of is going to the db and getting the `Category` object back and then adding it to Item but I would like to prevent trips to the db just to get back the id I already know.

Comment: Did you try making the `Category` property `virtual`? Also, are you using a custom guid ID generator function? That doesn't seem quite right...if you want to create your own ID, you should add the attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` to your primary keys. I think using auto-set properties for your primary key is causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your `Category` virtual, create the `CategoryId` property, and then specify it's the foreign key for `Category`.

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; };
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

With this, your first code (assign the `Id` directly) should work unless you "touch" the `Category` property or reference.

For this to work, make sure you haven't disabled proxies on the context

Also, make sure you don't set your `Id` properties to anything custom, let EF do its job